# Android drawable fonts not working suddenly

Tags: android, textview

I've been using drawable fonts for years now.
It's used by placing the ttf font in res/font/fontname.ttf, then implementing in TextViews:

```
   <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="Hello there!"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sansregular"/>
```

Suddenly, all my apps(newly and previously installed) stopped using the font provided.

Why did that happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This working fine!**

**styles.xml**

```
    <style name="txtLightFont" parent="android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sansregular</item>
    </style>

    <style name="txtRomanFont" parent="android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sansregular</item>
    </style>

    <style name="txtMediumFont" parent="android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sansregular</item>
    </style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="Hello there!"
            style="@style/txtLightFont"
            />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I just noticed that the activity with more number of views are not using fonts..others do. Why is that?

Comment: @Aksh this code working fine for me if raised any err. so please post err here.

Comment: no error..that's what stings. Just that activity with more views don't use font

Answer (score 0):

Make a font-family XML file inside font folder and then make style accordingly & use the style in TextView.

**font_family.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--Roboto-->

    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_medium"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

</font-family>
```

**style.xml** :

```
<style name="TextViewStyleRegular">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_12sdp</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewStyleMedium" parent="TextViewStyleRegular">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>
</style>
```

Hope you can do that!

Comment: Didn't work..tho I appreciate it. Seems like it's a bug.. as my code is working from api 16 to 28 except 23.

Comment: @Aksh have you try in programmatically way? bcoz it's working code for me.

Comment: I did...All is fixed now...tho I don't get why it happened in the first place.